# nlog - filter message based on the same threadname

Tags: nlog

Is it possible to use a filter on a bufferingwrapper? i want to send an email, with level = error and the the email should contain the last X log messages using a filter on the threadname that should be equal to the threadname where the error log event is raised).

if yes, how can we configure this in the configuration?

Comment: This is a difficult one, but I also curious what we are trying to implement. Could you provide some more info and elaborate on the example?